# React.useEffect running after .map used in return statement

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to create a react app that takes data from backend and displays it, and each data row from backend can have user defined number of inputs linked to it.
The code looks like this

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'

export default function Example(){

const [dataFromBackend,setDataFromBackend] = useState([])

const [val,setVal] = useState([[[]]])

const [usrInput,setUsrInput] = useState([[[]]])

React.useEffect(()=>{
const getData = async () =>{
fetch("url")
.then(response => response.json())
.then(setDatafromBackend)
}
getData()
},[])

React.useEffect(()=>{
const DataStructure = async () =>{
  let temp = [[[]]], temp2 = [[[]]]
  dataFromBackend.map((data,indx)=>{
  if(indx!=0)                                   //skipping indx == 0 temp[0] already there
  {temp = [...temp,[[]]]
   temp2 = [...temp2,[[]]]
   }
})
setVal(temp)
setUsrInput(temp2)
}
DataStructure()
},[dataFromBackend])

const handleAdd = (indx) =>{
let tempVal = [...val]
tempVal[indx] = [...tempVal[indx],[]]
setVal(tempVal)

let tempUsrInput = [...usrInput]
tempUsrInput[indx] = [...tempUsrInput[indx],[]]
setUsrInput(tempUsrInput)
}

const handleUsrInput= (indx,indx2) =>{
 let temp = [...usrInput]
 temp[indx][indx2] = e.target.value;
 setUsrInput(temp) 
}

const handleDelete = (indx,indx2) =>{
const deleteVal = [...val]
const deleteUsrInput = [...usrInput]

deleteVal[indx].splice(indx2,1)
deleteUsrInput[indx].splice(indx2,1)

setVal(deleteVal)
setUsrInput(deleteUsrInput)
}

return(
{dataFromBackend.map((data,indx)=>{
return(
   <div key ={indx}>
    <h1>{data.value}</h1>
    <button type="button" onClick = {e=>handleAdd(indx)}> Add </button>
     {val[indx].map((data2,indx2)=>{
      return(
             <div key ={indx2}>
             <input placeholder = "user input" value = {val[indx][indx2]} onChange = {e=>handleUsrInput(e,indx,indx2)}
             <button type="button" onClick = {e=>handleDelete(indx,indx2)}>x</button> 
             </div>
      )
      })
}
   </div>
)

})

}
)
}
```

so when I run this
error : val[indx] is not iterable or cannot read properties of undefined (reading : map)
now when I console.log val and data, val is not changed while data is already changed which causes val.length to be unchanged(=1) and not equal to the number of rows in dataFromBackend.

I do not know what I am doing wrong any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @DrDevil11 I think you need to check val[indx] value then you need to iterate it.

Comment: ok so i did something similar rather than checking for val[indx], I did val.length > indx && val[indx].map. so its working now thank you @ChetanBuddh